# Creating a snapchat settings like UI for android

Tags: android, xml

Is there a build-in Android class that has the capability of creating multiple rows with different texts with a view at the end in them just like in the attached image or the only possible way is to create multiple textviews with an imageView?

[image]

Comment: That is not a built-in UI; Snapchat seems to be wanting to mimic their iOS settings rather than use something that is more natural on Android. You can use `uiautomatorviewer` to see how they implemented it.

Comment: Copying iOS UI into an Android app is never a good idea, you'll confuse your users who are used to standard Android UI. Stick to available Android components, there are enough resources on the web on how to create a Preferences screen for an Android app.

Comment: @Egor non-related question: Can we have an ImageView instead of a checkbox in a preference screen activity?

Comment: @RedaM ask a new question for that

Comment: @RedaM, Sure, just define a subclass of Preference with the layout and behavior your use case requires.